# RedirectMatch 301 equivalent in Nginx

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, nginx

I'm a Apache user trying to use Nginx and I really can't understand how to convert `RedirectMatch 301`. Can someone give a better explanation of how it works?

- `.htaccess` version:

`RedirectMatch 301 /(tf2|cs|dota2|portal|hl|l4d|steam)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+) /$1/$3`

- My try on `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file:

`server {
rewrite "^/(tf2|cs|dota2|portal|hl|l4d|steam)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)" /$1/$3 last;
}`

It's intend to redirect for eg. `mysite.com/tf2/this-will-be-removed/this-will-not/` to `mysite.com/tf2/this-will-not/`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be :

```
server {

    server_name mysite.com;

    location / {
        rewrite "^/(tf2|cs|dota2|portal|hl|l4d|steam)/([-\w]+)/([-\w/]+)$" /$1/$3 permanent;
    }

}
```